# How to clear sum value in footer

Tags: gridview, datagrid, shieldui

I am using Aggregates functionality of ShieldUI grid to show sum of value in footer.But when I cliked on next page previous page sum value remains as it is.I also go through live demo example same thing happend.So please let me know how can I clear previous page sum value when clicked on next page.

Answer (score 1):

Set the footer field value to 0 in the DataBinding Event or in the PageIndexChanged event